# How to get handle to entries within SVG <g> group?

Tags: javascript, svg

Within a document, I can use `document.getElementById()` to get a handle to a particular unique element.

How can I do the same for a group, given as a parameter.

```
 <g id="right_hook">
  <circle id="wheeltap" r="3" stroke-width="1" />
  <path d="M 0 0 L 200 0 A 5,5 0 0,1 200,20" stroke-width="4" />
 </g>
```

If I pass this group to a function:

```
 function some( hook ) {
  var tap1= hook.wheeltap;    // does not work
  var tap2= hook.getElementById("wheeltap");   // does not work
}
```

What does work?

Reason I do this is I have multiple similar objects which I want to animate in JavaScript. I can of course give each of their subobjects globally unique names (s.a. "`right_hook_wheeltap`", "`left_hook_wheeltap`" but that sucks).

Comment: I can use the most recent browsers; and even be browser specific. Thanks for everyone's help. Eventually I will use jQuery but I want to understand it without, first.

Comment: Now using jQuery and I'd say to the reader just dropping in here, do it. Way easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` is trying to find an element by it's unique ID. The [DOM specification states:](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId)

> `getElementById`... Returns the Element
>   whose ID is given by elementId. If no
>   such element exists, returns null.
>   **Behavior is not defined if more than one element has this ID**.

If you have a reference to the hook element you're interested in, then I'd suggest using [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-A6C9094) (which returns a collection of elements with the specified tag name):

```
function some( hook ) {
  var taps = hook.getElementsByTagName("circle");
  var tap1 = taps[0]; // should contain the element you're looking for
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, as Tzury Bar Yochay says, if jQuery.SVG is an option it would make selectors a lot easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I just looked at [this one](http://people.mozilla.com/~vladimir/demos/photos.svg) and think that might use `childNodes` for the task.

e.g.

```
getElementById("SVG").childNodes
```

BTW, have a look at jQuery.SVG plugin ([link](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html))

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) for doing that, if you are fine with requiring rather recent browser releases.

What you want seems to be [QuerySelector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselector):

```
var rh = document.getElementById("right_hook");
var wheel = rh.querySelector("#wheeltap");
```

I haven't verified that it works with non-unique ID:s though.